# Used tables for layout, need to convert to CSS?

Tags: html, css

I've built a site with tons of pages and have used tables because I am new to coding and they're easy to use. I used Chrome to do all of my testing and stuff but I've recently found that Internet Explorer doesn't show certain table elements like border colours and my tables barely work at all with Firefox.

My PROBLEM is that my entire site is laid out using tables, this one specific example below is correct to use a table yes but it's just an example to show how I code my tables.

I've been looking at CSS for hours now, trying various tutorials/guides but I can't get my head around it, every time I get somewhere something happens and I have to start from scratch.

Right, scratch what I put before. Here's 2 screenshots. The one that looks fine is Google Chrome, the other is Firefox:

[image: Chrome]

[image: Firefox]

Now here's the code:

```
<style>
table.fix{
table-layout: fixed;
font-size: 90%;
}

</style>

<table BORDERCOLOR="grey" style="width: 60%;" align="left"  class="fix">
<tr>
<td><?php echo "<b>Subject: ",$subject,"</b>"; ?></td>
</tr>
</table>

<table BORDERCOLOR="grey" style="width: 40%;" align="right"  class="fix">
<tr>
<td><?php echo $datesent; ?></td>
</tr>
</table>

<table BORDERCOLOR="grey" style="width: 100%;"class="fix">
<tr>
<td><?php echo $message; ?></td>
</tr>
</table>

<table BORDERCOLOR="grey" align="left"  class="fix">
<tr>
<td><?php echo "From: <a href='viewprofile.php?userid=$fromuser'>",$id2," </a>"; ?></td>
</tr>
</table>

<table class="fix">
<tr>
<td><input type='submit' name='reply' value='Reply' onclick="location.href='sendmail.php?user=<?php echo $fromuser; ?>&subject2=<?php echo $subject; ?>&replyto=<?php echo $id; ?>'"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Now all I need is it to look like it does on Chrome but on every browser :) Whether it's through CSS, tables whatever I don't care, as long as it works and you guys would recommend the method

EDIT- Don't know how but I got the hang of it, it's now working with the code below :)

```
<style>
table.fix{
table-layout: fixed;
font-size: 90%;
}

.template{
border-style: solid;
border-color: grey;
height: 25px;
}

.left {
float: left;
}

.right {
float: right;
}

.box{
width: 530px;
height: 150px; 
border-style: solid;
border-color: grey;
font-size: 90%;
}
.namebox{
border-style: solid;
border-color: grey;
}
```

```
<div style="width: 300px;" class="template left"><?php echo "<b>Subject: ",$subject,"</b>"; ?></div>
<div style="width: 223px;" class="template right"><?php echo $datesent; ?></div>
<div class="box"><?php echo $message; ?></div>
<div class="namebox"><?php echo "From: <a href='viewprofile.php?userid=$fromuser'>",$id2,"</a>"; ?></div>
<br /><center><input type='submit' name='reply' value='Reply' onclick="location.href='sendmail.php?user=<?php echo $fromuser; ?>&subject2=<?php echo $subject; ?>&replyto=<?php echo $id; ?>'" /></center>
```

Comment: There is no simple answer to your question Ben... Trial and error, lots of practice... why not show the code you've converted and to divs and we will try to help you from there.

Comment: @Ben: table for this issue is right choice, don't change it into divs. `table` isn't hell if you use it for table data, not for layouts.

Comment: @Aaron Okay I'll try it again now and post the results

Comment: @panther This is just an example, I have many tables that are not viewing correctly and that overlap eachother on these other browsers :(

Comment: Also @Ben as panther says, the above section is correct in table form. But if you're entire site is layed out using tables then this is where your problems will arise.

Comment: @Ben: so fix them, IE can show tables correctly as other browsers. But when you have table data, use table, nothing else. If you have problem with something real, show it us. You have somewhere error, but we don't know where when you didn't show it us.

Comment: I don't have a specific problem that needs fixing, I just know that I'm using tables to layout everything on my site, literally everything lol and I need to start using something else (I believe CSS is best for layout?)

Comment: Basically this comes down to "learn the basics of CSS". It's far too broad a topic for a SO question.

Comment: @Quentin I pointed out I have been trying to learn for hours lol

Comment: Right okay I think I will have another proper go at learning :) I'm not sure why I've been downvoted as when/if I post the answer, people will see that this question is very useful

Comment: If you do convert to div layout your code will be MUCH lighter, easier to maintain and also easier to style. Move all of your inline css out of the markup and use class names and ID's to control the layout. Table layout is good for tabular data and html emails and code that was written in 1995.

Comment: @lharb Yeah I've got the hang of it now :) No idea how I struggled so much, see my edit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use divs, you need to specify the class of a div.

```
<div>
<div>
    <div class="head">Cost Per Shard</div>
    <div class="head">Use</div>
    <div class="head">How many shards?</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="cont">1000 Gems</div>
    <div class="cont">VIP Resource</div>
    <div class="cont"><input type="text" name="gems2" /></div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="cont"></div>
    <div class="cont"></div>
    <div class="cont"><input type="submit" name="Trade2" value="Trade"/></div>
</div>
```

Then you must specify the classes:

```
.head
{
    width: 33%;
    display: inline-block;
    color: orange;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.cont
{
    width: 33%;
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: I see, but why is <b></b> needed when "font-weight: bold;" is there?

Comment: You're right, if you set bold by CSS you can remove <b></b>. I update the code

Comment: thanks this has helped. Can you tell me, I have 2 divs inside another div but the 2 divs are on different rows, I want them to be next to eachother, is this possible? - Nevermind I worked it out :)

Comment: You have two option:
- set width at the value you want and set "display:inline-block"
- set width at the value you want and set float attribute (check this: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp)

Answer (score -1):

your CSS:

```
.text
{
  style="color:white; 
  font-size: 0.8em";
}

.tablehead
{
  color: orange;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.teabledata
{
  color: white;
}
```

your HTML

```
<form action="gemshop.php" method="post">
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
<p class="text">Buy Shards</p>
  <tr>
     <td  class="tablehead">Cost Per Shard</td>
     <td  class="tablehead">Use</td>
     <td  class="tablehead">How many shards?</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td  class="tablehead">1000 Gems</td>
    <td  class="tablehead">VIP Resource</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="gems2" /></td>
</tr>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="Trade2" value="Trade"/></td>
</tr>
```

Hopes this answers your question...

Comment: I didn't vote on this but .text { style="color:white; font-size: 0.8em";} is not valid css.